# unable to run jupyter within pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

```
D:\Python\python.exe "D:\PyCharm 2018.2.1\helpers\pycharm\pycharm_load_entry_point.py" notebook --no-browser --ip 127.0.0.1 --port 8886 --port-retries=0
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | You likely want to use `jupyter notebook` in the future
[W 17:58:52.576 NotebookApp] Terminals not available (error was No module named 'winpty.cywinpty')
[I 17:58:52.579 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: D:\Python projects\Projects
[I 17:58:52.579 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
```

Whenever I run a x.ipynb file it returns the error msg above, i can only access jupyter in browser.
How can I run it within pycharm??

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Do you have a `notebook` that you want to run as a python script?  Starting `jupyter` in notebook mode starts a server that interacts with browsers.  That's different from running a `ipython` console.

Comment: is there a way that I can run .ipynb file within pycharm?

Comment: Not directly.  There are tools for converting notebooks to regular scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PyCharm as an IDE alternative for editing Jupyter notebooks in a browser, but it won't run a notebook server for you automatically. You can simply open *.ipynb file in PyCharm and it opens with a dedicated notebook editor. When you run a cell for the first time, it is going to ask you about the url of a running notebook, like `http://localhost:8888/?token=<token>`

You can get this url by running the following in a console:

```
jupyter notebook list
```

Running a notebook server is a separate thing. You can do it externally or use a built in 'Jupyer Notebook' run template (via 'Run...' menu'). When you start a server from inside PyCharm this way, you will get your notebook url in a run console.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, it worked. but I found jupyter in pycharm cant deal with input(), it returns: StdinNotImplementedError: raw_input was called, but this frontend does not support input requests.what should I do to fix this?

Comment: It is a known PyCharm limitation, unfrotunately: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14618

Comment: Some additional hints: After running Jupyter via console command `jupyter notebook`, use `jupyter notebook list` as mentioned, then in PyCharm press SHIFT+SHIFT and enter "Jupyter servers" to configure it. Then enter `http://localhost:8888` under "Configured Servers". When asked for the token, enter the token you got from the list command. You can use New > Scratch file > Jupyter file to instantly create a new notebook file.